# What is difference between get_data and get_fdata in Nibabel library?

Tags: python, nifti, nibabel

I'm working with Nibabel to read some .nii files. I came across different examples and some of them use get_data() function while some of them use get_fdata() function. I could not find what the difference is in their documentation ([nibabel manuel](http://nipy.org/nibabel/manual.html#manual)). Can anyone explain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found in their documentation the function-description.

[Link to the documentation](http://nipy.org/nibabel/reference/nibabel.dataobj_images.html)

> get_data(caching='fill')
>
> ```
> Return image data from image with any necessary scaling applied
> ```
>
> get_fdata(caching='fill', dtype=)
>
> ```
> Return floating point image data with necessary scaling applied
> ```

So to be short... the **get_fdata** function takes a float as parameter and return a floating point of that image data. Further informations about how they work are in the documentation.

Comment: There is also a warning that says get_data will be deprecated in the future and get_fdata should be used. thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yep right. So if you want to use your application in long term i would recommend to use get_fdata. 
No problem!

Comment: According to their [developer documentation](https://nipy.org/nibabel/devel/biaps/biap_0008.html), the developers of nibabel believe that loading the image with the original but possibly small data type (such as 16-bit integer) may silently cause some issues like overflow.

Answer (score 1):

**get_fdata() :-** provides a more standardized and user-friendly way to access image data by converting it to floating-point values, suitable for many common use cases without manual data type conversion.

**get_data() :-** preserves the original data type and scaling, which may require additional handling based on specific analysis needs but ensures fidelity to the original data.